# Differences between object movement functions

Tags: unity

So I was trying to understand the differences between different ways to move an object in Unity and got opposite answers in different places. Here is what I was able to figure out though. I would ask you to check and correct me if I am wrong at any of them:

- transform.Translate has nothing to do with the physics. It simply **teleports** the object from point A to point B.
- MovePosition for **kinematic** bodies **slides** (instead of teleporting) the object from point A to B + interpolates the object position in the frames to be rendered in-between FixedUpdate calls.
- MovePosition for **non-kinematic** bodies ( aka dynamic ) **teleports** them from point A to point B.

Comment: Don't forget to include velocity or force-based methods. In my experience, I've found them to be the most reliable and consistent in how they interact with other physics objects.

Comment: @DMGregory ♦, I am not very familiar with the API, so can you tell me what functions are you talking about exactly? :)

Comment: Nothing complicated or cryptic, just the ones with "force" or "velocity" in their names.